# Angular - ngx-translate - Checking if translate key exist with Angular

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I use ngx-translate in my Angular application.

My HTML template:

```
<span [ngClass]="(role === 'ADMIN') ? 'badge badge-danger' : 'badge badge-success'">{{ 'ADMIN.USER.ROLES.' + role | translate }}</span>
```

My i18n json file:

```
"ADMIN": {
  "USER": {
    "ROLES": {
      "ADMIN": "Administrator",
      "FOO": "Auditor FOO",
      "DOO": "Auditor DOO",
      "ROO": "Auditor ROO",
      "unknown": "Unknown"
    }
  }
}
```

If my role is `BIPBIP`, I want use 'ADMIN.USER.ROLES.unknown' key.

I looking for a HTML template solution (**NOT Javascript**):

```
this._translateService.get("app.key").subscribe(res=>{
    if(...) {
        // message does not exist
    }
    else {
        // message exists
    }
}))
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since I found no way to safely check for the presence of a translation, the best thing I could do is to check for equality synchronously:

```
hasTranslation(key: string): boolean {
  const translation = this.translateService.instant(key);
  return translation !== key && translation !== '';
}
```

However, [I filed an issue with ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/1128), asking for an official check method.

So, for your template you could just test with `hasTranslation(x) ? ... : ...`

Answer (score 0):

I really think this should be done with a function in JavaScript.  Assuming you have an object with this mapping called `ADMIN`, you can do it like this.

```
<span [ngClass]="(role === 'ADMIN') ? 'badge badge-danger' : 'badge badge-success'">{{ this.ADMIN.USER.ROLES[role] ? 'ADMIN.USER.ROLES.' + role : 'ADMIN.USER.ROLES.unknown' | translate }}</span>
```

Comment: @sgrillon You have to create that as a variable in the component that the HTML template is being used by.  It should use the object from i18n.json.

Comment: this.ADMIN do not exist

Comment: @sgrillon I understand that. I am telling you to create something with that information from `i18n.json`. So you need to create ADMIN or whatever you want to call it in your component.  There is absolutely no way this will work without getting that information.

Comment: you use ngx-translate?

Comment: No I don't actually. I was just telling you how I would go about it with what you provided.  You can very easily create a loader (https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#write--use-your-own-loader), but you created the constraint of a HTML only solution.  Do with my answer what you will.

Answer (score 0):

In ngx-translate if translation does not exist the string of the key will be retured directly, so try this :

```
{{ ('EQUIPMENT-TYPE' + equipment.type.name | translate) !== 'EQUIPMENT-TYPE' + equipment.type.name  ?  ('EQUIPMENT-TYPE' + equipment.type.name | translate) : equipment.type.name }}
```

Thanks to https://www.nuomiphp.com/eplan/en/390812.html